# AS3 - Check results from an array and add to a counter

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I am trying to make a video quiz and when you click it adds a value of 1 to an array. The array size goes up to [9] and I am trying to read from the array so that if there is a value of 1 in the array between [0] and [9] it will add 1 to the counter.

I have got it working for just the first value in the array so I know it works, but I am not sure about how to make it read from all of the array to check for values of 1.

Heres my code so far:

```
if (clickTimes[0] == 1)
{
counter2++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Better yet, use a `for each...in` loop. It's really no different from a regular `for` loop, but it does provide some synactic sugar.

```
for each (var i:int in clickTimes)
{
    if (i == 1)
    {
        counter2++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the beauty of it...

`counter2 = clickTimes.join('').replace(/0/g, '').length;`

It puts all your values in one string, remove the zeros and counts the characters left.

Answer (score 1):

```
var clickTimes:Array = [1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0] // 5 1's and 4 0's
var counter2:int = 0

clickTimes.forEach(function(obj:*){
                       if (obj == 1){
                           counter2++;
                       }
                   })

trace(counter2) // traces 5
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a loop?

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < clickTimes.length; ++i)
{
    if (clickTimes[i] == 1)
        counter2++;
}
```

This would increment `counter2`, for each element that has a value of 1, in the `clickTimes` array.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this works for the just 1 click but doesn't seem to be working for anymore than 1.

I am outputting counter2 in a dynamic text box if that helps.

Comment: @jjhilly So are you trying to increment `counter2` if there is at least 1 click?

Comment: @david In frame 1 there is a video with errors in it, if you identify these by clicking in the right time it adds the value 1 to the array, there are 10 errors to identify. On the next frame it shows the results, so I am trying to read from the array and then add the score to a counter so that I can output it as a string in a dynamic text box.

Comment: @jjhilly Seems to me that there's an easier way to do this. Just make a score variable and increment it every time an error is identified, and set the text box to that value.

Comment: @David I have do as you have suggested, but it seems the whole problem may lie with my dynamic text box. 

`code` if (scores > 0)
{
 resultText.text = String (+scores);
}
else
{
 resultText.text = "0";
}

Comment: @jjhilly Why is there a `+` next to scores?

Comment: @David I was just trying it out, It doesn't make any difference if the + is there or not.

Comment: @jjhilly Run a `trace()` test to see if `scores` comes up with anything.

Comment: @David I have ran a trace and I do get the score through to the results frame, it just doesn't seem to want to display a number more than 1 in the dynamic text box.

Comment: @David Thanks for the help David, I made a rookie error. I had embeded the font but didnt click the little +, so the whole reason was because I hadn't actually embeded haha

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `if`. Just the following:

```
var clickTimes:Array = [1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0] // 5 1's and 4 0's
var counter2:int = 0;

for each (var i:int in clickTimes)
{
    counter2 += i;
}

trace(counter2); //5
```